# Why ConnectionError using python in docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker-compose

I have this

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  bd_mySql:
    image: mysql:5.7     
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: razvan
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PepitoElDeLosPalotes
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PepitoElDeLosPalotes
      MYSQL_DATABASE: equipojugadores
  api:
    build: data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
  python:
    build: python
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on: 
      - api
```

dockerfile (python)

```
FROM python:latest

ADD scraper.py /

RUN pip install BeautifulSoup4
RUN pip install html5lib
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install lxml

CMD [ "python", "scraper.py" ]
```

[image: Some of my python code]
And i have this error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8084):

why?

Comment: Does the `api` container start up properly? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: the database and the api start....

Comment: Probably not as fast as the python one does., You might wanna add some delay to the python script.

Comment: There is some of my scraper.py

Comment: Be aware that each container gets its own isolated network stack, so they each get their own IP and their own "localhost".  Connecting to "localhost" in a container will (usually) never connect you to a process in another container.  Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for what actually gets setup for you and how you can connect from 1 container to another

Answer (score 1):

Your `scraper.py` code is trying to connect to `localhost:8004`, however you have placed the service that advertises port `8004` on a separate container. This is similar to if you had placed it on a separate machine, and so `localhost` won't reach it. Instead, you have to use `api:8004`, which will resolve to the IP of the `api` container, which is where you put this service.

Comment: Ok, but if i want to run that docker-compose in other pc the ip gonna change, soo will not work.

Comment: `docker-compose` automatically makes `api` resolve to whatever the IP of the `api` container is, so it will work everywhere except when run outside of `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 0):

Your py code is trying to connect with localhost for that you need provide links in python part.
After that you can call the request http://api:8084/apiname.
This worked for me:

```
api:
    build: data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8084:8084"
python:
    build: python
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on: 
      - api
    links:
      - api
```